# Problems with ipython notebook Tex

Tags: math-mode

I'm using ipython notebook with the following Tex code

```
%%latex

We begin with the formulation of Maxwell's Laws. \newline
Once
\begin{aligned}
\nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{B}} -\, \frac1c\, \frac{\partial\vec{\mathbf{E}}}{\partial t} & = \frac{4\pi}{c}\vec{\mathbf{j}} \\
\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathbf{E}} & = 4 \pi \rho \\
\nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{E}}\, +\, \frac1c\, \frac{\partial\vec{\mathbf{B}}}{\partial t} & = \vec{\mathbf{0}} \\
\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathbf{B}} & = 0
\end{aligned}
```

The    %%latex just creates a Tex environment.
If I run the code, I get:

```
We begin with the formulation of Maxwell's Laws. \newline Once
∇×B⃗ −1c∂E⃗ ∂t∇⋅E⃗ ∇×E⃗ +1c∂B⃗ ∂t∇⋅B⃗ =4πcj⃗ =4πρ=0⃗ =0
```

And the output is correct in that it's in columns, not rows. The problem is I don't know why the \newline is not creating another line.

If try something like:

```
%%latex
\begin{document}
We begin with the formulation of Maxwell's Laws. \newline
Once
\begin{aligned}
\nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{B}} -\, \frac1c\, \frac{\partial\vec{\mathbf{E}}}{\partial t} & = \frac{4\pi}{c}\vec{\mathbf{j}} \\
\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathbf{E}} & = 4 \pi \rho \\
\nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{E}}\, +\, \frac1c\, \frac{\partial\vec{\mathbf{B}}}{\partial t} & = \vec{\mathbf{0}} \\
\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathbf{B}} & = 0
\end{aligned}
\end{document}
```

it still doesn't work.

Am I missing some begin-end statements? Do I have to initialize anything?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does the same problem happen if you try to compile the same code outside iPython?

Comment: `aligned` needs to be within a math-environment, e.g. `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}\end{equation}`

Comment: On second thought, this is actually off-topic here, as the question  doesn't really have anything to with LaTeX. The `%%latex` magic is a bit of a misnomer as I understand it, it only activates MathJax, which isn't (La)TeX. `\newline` doesn't work because LaTeX has nothing to with the rendering of the Notebook itself (unless you export it of course), and it is not inside any math, so MathJax doesn't do anything either.  The HTML tag `</br>` works. Generally, questions about the Notebook should be asked at [so].

Comment: The only thing that could be on topic here is how to write a specific math expression, or perhaps how to deal with a `.tex` file generated by `nbconvert`. The former is also borderline on-topic at best, as MathJax isn't LaTeX, it only shares some of the syntax.